# Creating a Jcombobox with multi select functionality in swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a multi select list with Jcombobox displaying object of my custom class. Initially i thought i will write a renderer and and paint a jcheckbox inside it so that user will be able to select multiple items. I also looked on internet for such type of implementations. My problem is when user selects multiple checkbox, jcombobox shows only the last selected checkbox item value as its label. I wanted in this way 
Checkbox item1, Checkbox item2 
Or item1, item2 can also suffice my requirement.

Also when i ask for selected items i should get both selected items.

Please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `JList`, seriously.  How would you display the selected item when it's collapsed?

Comment: Well, a textbox, a button and a jlist may suffice. But i cant make a button paired with textbox that looks like combobox and open jlist to the whole width of textbox + button. Any help is appreciated.